# Making several SVG icons using one layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, visualisation, svg

I need to make several different SVG icons in the same size.
I am using a list with numbered SVG from 1 to 262:

[image]

The obvious way is to make a different layer for each SVG.

I have tried to change the SVG icon from the Layer Styling bar, but whatever I did I only get the same SVG over and over again

[image]

Is there a way to use different SVG with one layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always get the same symbol because you used a `Single symbol` renderer, so it will render all the features with the same SVG icon.

Instead, you may try to use a `Categorized` renderer (assuming that you have stored the Country's name in a field, otherwise it should be very easy to do it as a preliminary operation). Once you have set a field for the categorization, you will be able to assign a custom SVG icon to each category.